# Append column to df based on values in of lists in array python

Tags: python, arrays, list, dataframe

I have a df with a Time column and values at each of these time points that could be looking something like this just much bigger:

```
df <- data.frame("Time" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,...), "value1" = c(1,2,7,45,2,0...), "value2" = c(...), ...)
```

I then have an array with multiple lists like this:

```
array([list([21.022]),
       list([81.043, 81.884, 82.805, 83.406, 83.926, 84.287, 84.487, 84.967, 85.728, 86.249, 86.689]),
       list([156.0, 156.681, 157.321, 158.363, 159.003, 159.524]),
       list([170.535, 171.296, 171.896, 172.617, 172.897, 173.658, 174.259, 175.06, 175.58, 175.941])],
      dtype=object)
```

These lists all represent time points in the df above.

I would like to append a column with 1 or 0 to the df based on whether the Time values are in any of the lists or not.

Thank you all for your help!!

Comment: Can you clarify whether this question is about Python or R? It's tagged with both.

Comment: hey, sorry - just python!